# How do I do an einsum that mimics 'keepdims'?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

a python question: I've got a np.einsum operation that I'm doing on a pair of 3d arrays:

```
return np.einsum('ijk, ijk -> ik', input_array, self._beta_array)
```

Problem I'm having is the result is 2d; the operation collapses the 'j' dimension. What I'd love to do is to have it retain the 'j' dimension similar to how 'keepdims' works in the np.sum function.

I can wrap the result in np.expand_dims, but that seems inefficient to me. I'd prefer to find some way to tweak the einsum to output what I'm after.

Is this posible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I can wrap the result in `np.expand_dims`, but that seems inefficient to me

Adding a dimension in numpy is at worst O(ndim), so basically free. Crucially, the actually data is not touched - all that happens is that the `.strides` and `.shape` tuples get an extra element each

There is no way right now to use einsum to directly get what you want.

You could try to make a pull-request against numpy to support something like `ijk, ijk -> i1k`, if you really think it improves readability

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, it's a minor thing on my end, just wishing I could streamline the code as much as possible.